# How To Probability/Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, book-recommendation

Just wondering if anyone can recommend and statistics/probability books for me to read? Context is, I’m a 2nd year maths student and with a strong background in calc, lin algebra, analysis and physics-y type modules. Unfortunately I haven’t really done any prob/stats at all as I changed from a joint honours maths and physics to straight maths and it wasn’t covered in any detail last year. I’m really looking for something to dip my toes in every now and again as I don’t really have time until mid December to get heavily involved in. If anyone has a suggestion in the same style as ODEs by Tenenbaum and Pollard, that’d be great - really enjoyed that book.
Cheers!

Comment: You can try good online course instead of a book, like [this](https://www.edx.org/course/probability-the-science-of-uncertainty-and-data)

Comment: duplicates https://math.stackexchange.com/q/468359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly suggest Grimmett and Walsh, Probability - An Introduction

http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~richard/teaching/f2017/GW_2014.pdf

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For probability theory I will recommend An Introduction to Theory of Probability Vol-1 and Vol-2 by William Feller, This book is a little old but really very nice for each concept in depth. Thank you.