# Probability and statistics introductory reference.

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am taking a course in probability and statistics for the  first time.
I have no idea about this subjects (on a undergraduate level)

I have been  given this three references.

1. [A Modern Introduction to Probability and Statistics:  Understanding Why and How](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B00DZ0PKLG/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_ptqhFbYQP8J0S)
2. [An introduction to  Probability Theory and it's application by William Feller](https://www.amazon.in/dp/8126518057/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_3wqhFbY7RK0QE)
3. [A first course in Probability by Sheldon Ross](https://www.amazon.in/dp/1292024925/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_.zqhFb442FKP2)

Please give a short review about the book and which is better for  beginners.
(Specifically for the 1st book)

Comment: duplicates https://math.stackexchange.com/q/468359