# Book to self-learn probability

Tags: probability, reference-request, soft-question

I am reading some lecture notes (completed with exercises and competition-like problems) provided by my college professor, but I would like to study probability from a proper book. Can you suggest one with good problems and clear rigorous style?

Comment: Googling for "probability book math.stackexchange" reveals this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31838/what-is-the-best-book-to-learn-probability

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best book to learn probability?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31838/what-is-the-best-book-to-learn-probability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start the ball rolling: here is a text book that I use and it has wonderful examples, and it really pushes me (not saying much) but it is undergrad level at least [Grimmett prob. And random processes](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/0198572220?pc_redir=1409427248&robot_redir=1)