# Book recommendation: introduction to probability theory

Tags: probability, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book that serves as an introduction to probability theory. I barely know anything about this branch of mathematics but if possible I'd like it to involve plenty of analysis since that's what i've studied a bit of thus far. I'd like it to have a lot assignments as well. I'd prefer if it's more focused on pure mathematics and I want plenty of rigorous proofs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best book to learn probability?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31838/what-is-the-best-book-to-learn-probability)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used 'Elementary Probability', by D. Stirzaker, and 'A First Course on Probability', by S. Ross.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that they're available online for free which is great.

Answer (score 1):

I heard from my friend who is a PhD student doing research in Probability, that he recommends "Real Analysis and Probability", by Dudley.  Here is its  [amazon page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521007542) .  
 He said it is clear, detailed, thorough, and doesn't skip steps. Also, it helped him transition from "undergraduate" probability to measure-theoretic probability.  From his comments and the amazon reviews, it seems to match your criteria of "plenty of analysis", "focused on pure mathematics", and "plenty of rigorous proofs".  I haven't read it yet, but it's definitely on my reading list.

Comment: Perhaps i'll get around to it at a later point, it seems a bit too advanced for me at this moment. It does sound intressting however. I've never studied probability theory before so perhaps it's a good idea to settle for something simpler initially.

Comment: No problem, wish you the best as you learn probability; it is a beautiful area of study.