# Suggestions for books on probability theory

Tags: probability, measure-theory, book-recommendation

I am taking a course name "mathematical foundations of probability theory" and the lecturer is following the book "probability" by A.N shiryaev. I am finding very hard to follow and would appreciate if someone could recommend a book with similar content or at least a big overlap so that I could perhaps follow better. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31838/what-is-the-best-book-to-learn-probability

Comment: @Jotabeta Thanks. Perhaps, I am looking for a book that follows same principles, so that I don't divert, but will take a look

Answer (score 3):

The textbooks by Durrett and Billingsley are most often used. I really enjoy the text by Breiman every time I open it. See also the book by Grimmett and Stirzaker. You might find the slides on Scott Sheffield's website helpful.