# Good resources for learning Probability

Tags: probability, reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [probability textbooks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90349/probability-textbooks)

I recently started taking Probabilistic Graphical Models on coursera, and 2 weeks after starting the course I am beginning to believe that I am not that great in Probability and as a result of that I am not even able to follow the first topic (Bayesian Network). That being said, I want to make an effort to learn this course, so can you suggest to me some other resources  for Probability which can be helpful in understanding this course

Comment: on other questions on this site and SEs CV site we have answered questions about books to learn about probability.  There are many good books that can be recommended but of course they are aimed at different levels of assumed background in mathematics.  To provide the most suitable references for you I think we would need to know something about your background in mathematics/probability and statistics and the level that the course book is written at.

Comment: Here are few similar questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17604/self-study-resources-for-basic-probability?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90349/probability-textbooks?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125418/suggestion-on-good-probability-theory-book?rq=1

Comment: One from the CV website http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15692/probability-theory-books-for-self-study

Comment: Your course has a textbook  *Probabilistic Graphical Models: Principles and Techniques* by Daphne Koller and Nir Friedman. This book has an introductory chapter on probability and graph theory.